# Java table not created from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This mysql script does not work correctly. I tried executing the query to create tables in the phpmyadmin and it worked. The database is created but the table does not get created and I do not get any errors/stack traces.
This is my code

```
public void createDatabase() {
    java.sql.Connection conn = null;
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
       try{
          // Register JDBC driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

          // Open a connection
          System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
          System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

          // Create database
          System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String createdatabase = "CREATE DATABASE TimePoints;";
          stmt.executeUpdate(createdatabase);
          System.out.println("Created the database.");

          // Create table
          System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String createtable = "CREATE TABLE players (playername VARCHAR(38), playertime BIGINT);";
          stmt.executeUpdate(createtable);
          System.out.println("Created the table.");

       }catch(SQLException se){
          // Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){
          // Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
          // Finally block used to close resources
          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
          }// do nothing
          try{
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          } //end finally try
       } //end try
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

Comment: Post the script as part of your question.

Comment: It is in part of my question. Click the pastebin link I included.

Comment: No, that's not part of your question. Only the link pointing to an external place is part of the question. I cannot see any MySQL code in your question.

Comment: add a print stacktrace inside catch(SQLException se) in the finally clause

Comment: Just right under finally or in one of the methods down there?

Comment: I'm sure you should either use a qualified tablename like ` String createtable = "CREATE TABLE TimePoints.players (playername VARCHAR(38), playertime BIGINT);";` or switch the context to your newly created database.

Comment: Seems to have worked.

Comment: How can I check if a user exists in the table? Just check for the playername varchar? Method to get their name is player.getName();

Comment: @Andrew i appreciate your effort.in your code you create database then table .ok so you have to insert users in to that table .this can be done from a registration panel or other interface